# Hyper-V Server VM stuck at boot and I cannot delete it

Tags: windows, powershell, virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I am using Microsoft Hyper-V server with Admin center. Admin center says: VM Status: Paused-Critical Powershell says: VM status : In service. After server restart one of the virtual machines is stuck at starting. I tried stop the VM via Powershell, unable to delete.  Unable to kill vmwp.exe process by ID via Powershell.  The files are in use... Rebooting HOST Server - no luck, same...

Comment: Welcome to Servfault.  Can you add some bits of critical information.  1.  Windows Server Version.  2.  Can you ping the guest?  3.  Guest OS version.  4.  Fully patched or not.  5.  Powershell version.  6.  Any event log errors in the host that are relevant?  7.  The powershell commands you ran and what result you were looking for when you ran those commands.   Thanks for the question.  When you add the additional info, edit your question and add it in rather than stringing a bunch of comments back and forth.  People will be more likely to answer your question if add the above data to it.

Answer (score 6):

Power off your host, mount disk with VMs with some other Windows Server box and delete VM files manually from there.

P.S. Don't use Windows Admin Center (WAC), use PowerShell to manage and monitor your Hyper-V cluster. WAC is just one big can of worms (and bugs).

Comment: How can i do it remote? :D

Comment: It’s easy! https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7